# How to integrate sonarqube with a visual studio solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sonarqube

I have installed SonarQube server and we have a requirement to integrate one of our visual studio project solution with SonarQube to analyse our code and receive code quality suggestions. 
Currently we were not able to find a suitable guideline in how to set it up. Appreciate if you can provide a clear guideline to solve our problem.

Thank You

Comment: See the .Net Solution on following : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS

Comment: hi @jdweng we actually installed sonarqube server. But our requirement is to connect to the server from Visual Studio 2013 via VSSonarExtensions, so that our project is analysed and the analysis is shown in SonarQube dashboard

Comment: See : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2013

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner a integrate Sonar with VS using Build Events

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/09/28/quickstart-analyzing-net-projects-with-sonarqube-msbuild-or-visual-studio-online-and-third-party-analyzers-stylecop-resharper/#_Executing_the_MSBuild.SonarQube.Run

Using Build Events
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ke5z92ks(v=vs.120)